# If $\xi$ is the Riemann xi function then value of $\xi'(1/2)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Riemann Xi function is defined as $$\xi(s)=\frac{s(s-1)}{2}\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s)$$
**Question** What is the derivative of $\xi(s)$ at $\frac{1}{2}$?

**My try**
Logarithmic differentiation gives $$\frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)}=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{log(\pi)}{2}+\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{s}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})}+\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$$
At, $s=\frac{1}{2}$
$$\frac{\xi'(\frac{1}{2})}{\xi(\frac{1}{2})}=-\frac{log(\pi)}{2}+\frac{\Gamma'(\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}+\frac{\zeta'(\frac{1}{2})}{\zeta(\frac{1}{2})}$$

Comment: Try differentiating $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\xi(1/2+s)$ is even, $\xi'(1/2)=0$.